# Kali - Enable SSH by changing files on disk?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, hyper-v, kali-linux

I am working with a number of Kali images using various automation tools for a specific customer requirement. To cut a long story short I need to enable SSH on the Kali host but without actually 'using' the host itself. Is there a way to set SSH active by simply changing files on the hard disk? (i.e. so the changes would be picked up on boot/after a reboot).

I am able to start and stop the host (but cannot login or execute commands) and have root access to the HDD.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159293/101265) from Linux/UNIX:

> All systemctl enable does is create symlinks from
> /usr/lib/systemd/system/ or /etc/systemd/system/ to the appropriate
> target directories in /etc/systemd/system/, with services in the
> latter directory overriding ones in the former.
> ...
> Instead of using
> systemctl enable you could enable the netctl service manually with the
> following command:
>
> ```
> ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl.service \
> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netctl.servic
> ```